# I tried using angular 4 but i am unable to map function to map the response to json

Tags: angular

I tried using angular 4 but i am unable to map function to map the response to json.The error simply says that map is unrecognised even though I have imported rxjs.
    For some the error is because of angular cli version i.e downgrading the version helps but that did not solve the problem for me . If any suggestions ,please respond......

Comment: show some code..................

Comment: Maybe use `pipe(map())` insteed of `map`. You most likely imported different `map` (from operators) while you want `map` of `Observable`

Answer (score 0):

Try importing like this => **import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';**